# PHP scandir sees old deleted file, and fopen sees its contents

Tags: php, bash, file

I've encountered a very strange anomaly in some of my PHP code, and I need some help to figure out what's going on here.

---

The user has a directory of files, and the PHP relays the names and contents of all the files to the webpage.

It detects files with `scandir` and reads them with `fopen`.

Another PHP file is capable of deleting these files via `unlink`, which is called via a JavaScript AJAX request.

During my testing, I created a file called `_.txt` and later deleted it with the `unlink` file mentioned above.

This is where things got very weird.

In my workspace's file browser, the `_.txt` file is gone.

Using `ls` in a Bash terminal shows that the `_.txt` file is gone.

But the PHP `scandir` still detects that file, and `fopen` is able to successfully read its contents.

---

From this point, I created a new file via the Bash terminal with `touch _.txt`

I gave it some content with `nano _.txt`

The PHP correctly detects the file and reads the contents of the new `_.txt` file.

I then deleted it with `rm _.txt`

And now PHP still detects the `_.txt` file *and* still reads the content of the *old* `_.txt` file.

---

To make this problem even weirder, this does not happen with any other file I've created and deleted via these PHP commands. Only this one file, `_.txt`, is giving me all this trouble.

I've restarted the server several times since this started happening.

I've looked all over the web and can't find anything about this.

---

Code snippet responsible for scanning for and reading files:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
/*
password checks ommited as it's not relevant
*/
$directory = scandir('USERFILES/'.$username);
foreach($directory as $filename){
    // do not select . and ..
    if($filename != '.' && $filename != '..'){
        // by default this remains an empty string
        $fileusesunderscore = '';
        // if invalid characters start the filename
        if(strpos('0123456789.,-[]/+=\\`"\'!*:|@#%^&()<>?|;~', $filename[0]) !== false){
            // set the empty string to underscore
            $fileusesunderscore = '_';
        }
        // grab the file contents
        $file = fopen('USERFILES/'.$username.'/'.$filename, 'r');
        /*
        line at this position is responsible for echo'ing the file
        it is ommited as it is irrelevant, except that $fileusesunderscore is used like so when echoing:
        $fileusesunderscore.pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME)
        */
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

Code snippet responsible for deleting files:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
// filename can only possibly equal a name that was
// given to the JS by the first PHP file
$filename = $_POST['file'];
/*
password checks ommited as it's not relevant
*/
$filepath = '/USERFILES/'.$username.'/'.$filename.'.txt';
unlink(getcwd().$filepath);
```

---

So I guess to summarise, here's what I'm having trouble with and need help in achieving:

> File called `_.txt` was deleted via `unlink` and no longer exists.
>
> `scandir` still sees it and `fopen` still sees its contents.
>
> I cannot delete file with Bash `rm` because `_.txt` no longer exists.
>
> What I'm trying to do is successfully get rid of this file and prevent this from happening again.

I've been looking all over the place for a solution and can't find one, so I'm asking for help here. Thank you for taking time to help with this.

Comment: It sounds like file is opened in one process and deleted in other process while it is still opened. If this is the case, check if file is opened before deletion.

Comment: `unlink`, like `rm` removes the link from the directory to the file.  But the file is not released until all processes that have it open are gone.  It is the same problem if you delete some software log files, the space is *not* freed, even if the file is not seen in the directory.

Comment: I've rebooted the server several times since this started happening, but it's still there. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Old post but Ive been facing similar issue on my Kali linux.Been crazy for a few hours!
Solved by going into the directory as root(files where visually absent), in command line  tried a dir command as a last resort idea and then deleted files appeared as "name.jpg~".
Deleted them with rm command and every thing s fine!